# Blender object to Unity imported - low quality after scaling

Tags: unity, blender

I've created an object with Blender. Took the default cube and moved two of it's vertices inside, so I got the 'Ramp' shape. Now, I imported this into Unity and this is what happened when I tried to scale it on one axis:

Here's the one after scale:

[image]

It's edges are blurry.

Here's the 1:1:1 object, without a scale:

[image]

Looks strange to me, cause when I scale Cubes (built into Unity) they're not blurry.

If anyone has a clue, I'd be grateful!

Comment: Can you edit the file with notepad and post it here? It shouldn't be anything too big since a ramp is just 6 dots with 8 triangles.

Comment: But which file, the `.blend` one?

Comment: If this is being rendered as opaque geometry, then basically the only way this can happen is [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). This is a feature that reduces the appearance of "jaggies" or stairstep artifacts of rasterization by smoothing the rendered output in various ways. Can you try disabling anti-aliasing (check both your render settings in-Unity and in your graphics card's configuration), and report back whether that had any effect?

Comment: Wow, this actually works with higher Anti-Alias (it was set to 2 by default). What about performance on mobile devices here? Is it the good idea to set it to 8? Or just give an option in the user's options and let him choose?

Thanks Gregory, please post and answer and I'll accept it ;)